# Multiple return value method fails with goto statements

Tags: c++, function, goto

The following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int function(void)
{
    static int i,state=0;
    switch(state)
    {
         case 0: goto labeL0;
         case 1 :goto labeL1;         

    }

    labeL0:
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        state=1;
        return i;
        labeL1:;
    }

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << function() << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

fails. I mean it returns only `0` instead of `0,1,2,...`

I wanted just use label and `goto` statements to implement such functions. It is for practice (let's say homework), but I can't get it to work. Is this even possible?

How can I use `goto` and label statements so that this function prints `0 1 2...` so on?

Comment: Arguably the most awesome example of `goto` misuse I've seen in a while... Well done sir! :)

Comment: I don't understand. What is the program supposed to do? Print the number from 0 to 9?

Comment: yes exactly,you are right using goto and labels

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: function seems to be a generator returning an incremented number every time it is called. However, it is called only once.

Comment: @Martin James: you might like [coroutines in C based on Duff's device](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) then.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Aha, that example was used as inspiration for this code.  Both have the static local variables, a loop until 10 and return nothing when i >= 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do.  If your goal is
jsut to use `goto`, the simplest solution is to implement the algorithm
exactly as you'ld normally do, replacing looping constructs wit `goto`;
i.e. instead of:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i ) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl
}
```

you could write:

```
    int i = 0;
    goto label1:
label2:
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        ++ i;
label1:
        if ( i < 10 ) goto label2;
```

Back in the old days, with Fortran IV, this is what we actually did.
There's absolutely no reason to do it today (except maybe obfuscation).

I wonder, however, given the static variables, if you're not trying to
implement some sort of co-routine; that each time you call the function,
you output one higher than  the previous time.  In this case, I'd
recommend maintaining the state in a class, rather than using static
variables.  In addition the function will need some sort of return value
so that the caller will know when it's finished, and the caller will
have to loop.  Something like the following should do the trick:

```
class CoRoutine
{
    int i;
public:
    CoRoutine() : i( 0 ) {}
    bool function()
    {
        if ( i < 10 ) {
            std::cout << i <<std::endl;
            ++ i;
        }
        return i < 10;
    }
};

int
main()
{
    CoRoutine c;
    while ( c.function() ) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(There's still no need for `goto`, of course.)

Comment: you probably meant to define `operator () ()` method to create a functor. Then to call `c` you could use `c()`.

Comment: Why obfuscate when there is no reason to?  There are cases where the functor idiom is appropriate, but there's no indication that this is the case here.

Comment: I'd consider the name `CoRoutine` a big give away. How do you call a coroutine? It seems `f()` is the usual way and `f.function()` might be a bit obscure.

Comment: I presume that `function()` is just a placeholder for a meaningful name.  You call a coroutine like you call anything else, with, if possible, a name which says what it does.  `operator()()`, `f()` or `function()` are all bad choices.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work since after the `return` statement, the compiler leaves the function ignoring all statements after it.

Also, using labels is ugly, horrible and unmaintainable. Why are you using them? Do you want the maintenance guy arriving at your house with a chain-saw?

Comment: Note that the variables are `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursive call to function to get it executed and more over your use of GOTO is a typical example of why we should avoid using goto.

```
void function(void)
 {
     static int i=0;

     for(;i<10;)
     {         
         cout<<i;
         i++;
        function();
     }

}

void main()
{
 function();
}
```

but if you still want to use goto statements then use this

```
void function(void)
{
   static int i =0;
   lablelA:
   cout<<i;
   i++;
   if(i  == 10)
       return;
   goto lablelA;

}
```

Comment: Sadly, recursion and static local variables don't work well together.

Comment: thanks @Jeeva  such codes i have tested many times,just wanted   using return statment,but no problem,great!

Answer (score 1):

After executing the return statement the execution returns from function().....

So initially when i=0, "return i" returns 0 and it is displayed on screen

Answer (score 0):

Jumping to labeL1 is jumping in a loop with uninitialized variable i.  How could this go right?  This is only 1 of the reasons to avoid goto.

**EDIT**: actually, it should probably work as some sort of poor man's generator (because of the static local variables), but still the case of i >= 10 should be handled.  Now it is returning nothing.  So your main concern in the code is that you need a loop in main to call function maximum 10 times.

Still, this is not a construct I would want to see in real code.

Comment: Not initializing `i` is an error regardless of `goto` and you failed to address that. I don't think this answer in this state can help the OP fix his function.

Comment: @LucDanton: I first also overlooked that i and state are static, so this seems to work (in a horrible way).

Comment: @LucDanton: there is no error: `initial call` -> `state=0` -> `label0` -> `i=0`. Now `i` is initialized and it is static so there is no need to initialize it on subsequent calls to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The code reminds me of [`Coroutines in C`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html).

To print 0, 1, etc you should call the function several times. That's the whole point.